# Jenkins Job DSL Plugin - Include another Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins

I want to build a Common Jenkinsfile for a couple of Build Jobs in different languages. And then I want to add a specific Jenkinsfile that depends on some parameters.

For example: the common file should contain information about Docker Hub and Nexus Repository. It's always the same. And the specific file should contain language specific build steps.

Is it possible to "include" another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Pipeline Shared Groovy Libraries Plugin it is possible to define your own Job DSL. [This section](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/master/README.md#define-more-structured-dsl) of the plugin's manual explains how to do this.

Comment: that looks pretty good. thanks for the quick reply. I will give it a shot